# Same config for node.js and for browser javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, config

Is it possible to have the same config file for server node.js and client js code?

Now I use .json config for node.js, but can convert it to any format

Comment: In theory yes, but could you add more details on what you have in mind? Your question is a little too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information, all I can offer is a simple suggestion: [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/). You can reference a config module in the Node.js code and reference it in the client script. Just make sure that the config file can be served to the client.

```
// Example reference
var config = require('./data/config.js');
```

Comment: used require.js at client.